# allow the buddypress group administrator to add more admins

Tags: buddypress

is there a way to allow the current group administrator to add more administrators from the front-end .. does buddypress include such feature , and if not , do you know any plugin doing help in that ? or where i should start from to develop this in my own .. i'm trying to use buddypress group as fan page .. and the main function i need from the buddypress groups is the multi admins feature .. i want to give the users the ability to create pages and add more admins , something similar to fb fan page .. hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already possible to do that in BuddyPress.
Log in as a group admin, go to your group and open its "Manage" tab.
There you will see a subpage - Members. On this page, you will see the list of all members of the current group. If the member that you want to promote is not there - ask a user to join the group (or send him/her an invite). From "Manage -> Members" page you will be able to click on a "Promote to Admin" next to the member name - and thus the user will become an admin of this group.

More information can be found here: https://codex.buddypress.org/administrator-guide/groups/

Comment: thank a lot , i have figured this out when i added members to the group , i couldn't find it in first because the group was empty :) , anyway , i appreciate your help.

Comment: Ok. But I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as the correct one for future users. Thanks!